# Visual Studio runs but does not build with start button or F5

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My Visual Studio 2017 runs the last built version of a program when the start button or F5 key is pressed, but it will only reflect recent changes if I use Build -> Build Solution or ctrl + shift + B beforehand.

Even with keyboard shortcuts, it's often tedious to hit ctrl+shift+b to build (which is already awkward with one hand), wait till the solution compiles (which could be anywhere from a second to several minutes depending on the project), and then press F5 to run.

It would be a huge time and convenience saver if I could get a standard build + run shortcut working.  I'm not sure what setting I should be looking for, however.

**Update:**

Checking in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard, it looks like my Debug.Start is set to F5, so it's not a problem with the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Doesn't your Visual Studio compile (if necessary) when you press F5?

Comment: F5 does build + run

Comment: @WaiHaLee: No, it does not.  It just runs the last built version.  I didn't realize my VS had a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, the problem was this:

[image: screenshot]

Unchecking this box fixed the issue.  I was able to make a change in my code and simply hit F5 to see the new results.

This explains why VS *appeared* to be building *something*, but not changing the actual code I was working in.  Apparently, it was building some of the projects in my solution, but not the one I was working in.

Answer (score 2):

It's odd, but it sounds like your build options got configured to not build in certain scenarios.  On the Visual Studio menu go to

`Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run`

Ensure **On Run, when projects are out of date:** option is "Prompt to build" or "always".  Not "Never build".

And I also have my **On Run, when build and deployment errors occur** set to "prompt to launch", but that should't do what you describe.

**UPDATE**

As noted in the comments, this particular issue is resolved by toggling off  **Only Build startup projects and dependencies on run**.  There [was a time](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/10/01/did-you-know-how-to-build-just-the-startup-project-and-any-dependencies-325/) when this feature was off by default.  This feature defaulted to on for me in visual studio 2017 community edition.

> **Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run**
>   [Builds only the startup project and its dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-dialog-box-projects-and-solutions-build-and-run) when you use the F5 key, select
>   the Debug > Start menu command, or applicable commands on the Build
>   menu. If clear, all projects and dependencies are build.

[image]

Comment: I figured it out - it was the "only build startup projects and dependencies on run".

Comment: Sometimes the 'Only build startup projects and depencies' doesn't build the dependencies. In VS2022 I still have this issue, where it does build the start-up project. But just skips the dependencies. When I then attach the debugger on the files and lines I just changed, I get the warning that source file is different from the file build. I have to stop the project, manually Build -> Build. And then run again. Toggling off this feature worked, but ofcourse start-up time is a lot slower because it'll build everything.

Answer (score 1):

F5 does **build** (if you modified any of your sources, so that it makes sense to build the project) and then **run**.

If this doesn't work for you then you can try to restore settings to Visual C# (for example) and you'll get that functionality.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a full list of VS shortcuts that you can check.